# Angular routing for viewing specific content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Okay so i wasnt quite sure What to Call this question but it is Rather simple.

Say you have a list of users with each of their ids now when you click one of the users you want to go to a page showing only information about that user in php that would be `HTTP://example/user/show?id=1`

How would this work in angularjs using ui-router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to create a route file to navigate to the page Url such;

```
angular.module('moduleName', ['ui.router'])
 .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('usersProfile', {
      url: '/user/show?id',
      templateUrl: 'template path', //e.g userProfile.html
      controller: 'controllerName' //UserController
   });
}]);
```

Then, you can have something like this in your Html;

```
<div>
    <a data-ng-repeat="user in users" ui-sref="usersProfile({id: user.Id})">
        <h4>{{user.name}}</h4>
    </a>
</div>
```

create a controller(UserController) to retrieve the user info from the $stateParam and then you can display whatever you want on the userProfile.html.
You can always check this for more info [angularjs ui route](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)